# When exactly does tmpwatch clear out files I place in /tmp?

Tags: centos, tmp

CentOS 6.x

I'm confused on when exactly files I place in /tmp/ are deleted.

/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch has the following:

```
#! /bin/sh
flags=-umc
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" -x /tmp/.X11-unix -x /tmp/.XIM-unix \
        -x /tmp/.font-unix -x /tmp/.ICE-unix -x /tmp/.Test-unix \
        -X '/tmp/hsperfdata_*' 10d /tmp
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" 30d /var/tmp
for d in /var/{cache/man,catman}/{cat?,X11R6/cat?,local/cat?}; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        /usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" -f 30d "$d"
    fi
done
```

The section in line 5 that reads `-X '/tmp/hsperfdata_*' 10d /tmp` leads me to believe that files I place in /tmp/ will remain for 10 days (assuming they aren't locked during deletion of course or the directory is mounted on a tmpfs file system).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On CentOS 6, it would seem that `tmpwatch` is basing it's decision to delete on when a file was last accessed (atime). If it's been 10 days (10d) or more then it will be deleted when `tmpwatch` runs.

From the `tmpwatch` man page:

```
    By  default,  tmpwatch  dates  files  by their atime (access time), not 
    their mtime (modification time). If files aren't being removed when 
    ls -l implies they should be, use ls -u to examine their atime to see if 
    that explains the problem.
```

Also from the man page:

```
    The time parameter defines the threshold for removing files.  If the
    file has not been accessed for time, the file is removed.  The time 
    argument is a number with an optional single-character suffix specifying 
    the units: m for minutes, h for hours, d for days.  If no  suffix  is 
    specified, time is in hours.
```

Answer (score 7):

On RHEL7/CENTOS7, there's a systemd target that runs daily: `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` (to replace `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`). The default values are both `OnBootSec=15min` and `OnUnitActiveSec=1d`. Quoting [systemd.timer](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) manpage:

> OnBootSec= defines a timer relative to when the machine was booted up.
>
> OnUnitActiveSec= defines a timer relative to when the unit the timer is activating was last activated.

So the /tmp is now cleaned daily, roughly at the hour when system boot: **so the time is undefined**. For large deployments, not all virtual machines perform the cleanup simultaneously, nice.

For history, run:

```
$ journalctl  -u systemd-tmpfiles-clean
Mar 12 21:44:17 c7.klabs.be systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Mar 12 21:44:18 c7.klabs.be systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

Where "Started Cleanup" actually means "Complete".

Comment: The tmpwatch has a nice ability of using `fuser`. Can the systemd version do that?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, On April 2015, Lennart Poettering (SystemD developper) said on [systemd-devel mailing list](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2015-April/031344.html) : *"we do not support this [..] iterating through /proc is simply too bad.[..] we might consider it [otherwise]"* then he added *"**atime checks [..] should be fully sufficient.** Do you have a case where they aren't?"*

Comment: Yea I asked that question.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I was quoting Lennart Poettering on the mailing list. Reply to him (on the list) !