# When will Cent OS delete empty dirs in /tmp?

Tags: centos, tmp

On our webserver, we use `/tmp` to store a server-side cache. The cache path is unique for each website, and also for each git revision. So when the code is updated, the old cache folder is abandoned. The files therein are eventually deleted, but the folders themselves persist. This is not actually causing a problem (yet), but it seems messy. Is there any way to automatically delete folders in `/tmp` which have been empty for X days?

According to the man pages, `tmpwatch` should remove unused directories, but it is not doing so.

```
$ cat /etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch 
#! /bin/sh
flags=-umc
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" -x /tmp/.X11-unix -x /tmp/.XIM-unix \
    -x /tmp/.font-unix -x /tmp/.ICE-unix -x /tmp/.Test-unix \
    -X '/tmp/hsperfdata_*' 10d /tmp
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" 30d /var/tmp
for d in /var/{cache/man,catman}/{cat?,X11R6/cat?,local/cat?}; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    /usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" -f 30d "$d"
    fi
done
```

I see nothing there which would stop it removing directories.

However, `ls -ul` shows that all directories in `/tmp` (well, all that I checked) have been accessed *today*, even ones which shouldn't have been touched in months.

Comment: use: `crontab`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is given in [When exactly does tmpwatch clear out files I place in /tmp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118754/when-exactly-does-tmpwatch-clear-out-files-i-place-in-tmp) (I suppose that makes the question a duplicate but I cannot mark it as such).

Comment: from [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared) `centos7` its configured in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding option `--dirmtime` to the `tpmwatch`
commands so that access time is not checked for directories, despite the `-u`.
(changing `flags='-umc --dirmtime'` will not do as you also need to remove the double-quotes from `"$flags"`).