# crontab job deleted my file in /tmp

Tags: centos, cron

I have used RHEL6/CentOS6 before and some application work good on my system.
Now I have a new CentOS 7 installation,something confused me.
I create a cron job with user `myuser`, like this:

```
*/4 * * * * echo "hello" > /tmp/test.txt
```

There is some files in `/tmp` directory, such as `myfile1,myfile2...myfile`, all these file belongto `myuser`
This cron works fine in my RHEL6 system,but in CentOS7 all files belong to `myuser` in `/tmp` will be deleted as long as the cron job execute
I find these in `/var/log/cron`

```
Aug 15 21:03:01 zw_21_66 crond[15029]: (myuser) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/mrd)  
Aug 15 21:04:01 zw_21_66 CROND[11762]: (myuser) CMD (echo "hello" > /tmp/test.txt)
```

and these in journalctl

```
Aug 15 21:04:01 zw_21_66 systemd[1]: Created slice user-1001.slice.  
Aug 15 21:04:01 zw_21_66 systemd[1]: Starting user-1001.slice.  
Aug 15 21:04:01 zw_21_66 systemd[1]: Started Session 11530 of user myuser.  
Aug 15 21:04:01 zw_21_66 systemd[1]: Starting Session 11530 of user myuser.  
Aug 15 21:04:01 zw_21_66 CROND[11762]: (myuser) CMD (echo "hello" > /tmp/test.txt)  
Aug 15 21:04:02 zw_21_66 systemd[1]: Removed slice user-1001.slice.  
Aug 15 21:04:02 zw_21_66 systemd[1]: Stopping user-1001.slice.
```

I have checked tmpfile.d but found nothing; how can I find the killer who deleted my file?

Recently I solved this problem by edit `/etc/pam.d/crond`,Commented out entry:

```
#session    include    password-auth
```

But I have no idea why it works， any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just getting hit with the RHEL7 /tmp cleanup job in systemd? Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118754/when-exactly-does-tmpwatch-clear-out-files-i-place-in-tmp for more information.

Comment: Thx.I have read it, and checked systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer in my system.I'm sure that myfile was deleted when cron job execute.Shall i edit my post?

Comment: Can you install `sysdig`? If so, what does something like the following show going on? `sysdig -p '%proc.pname[%proc.ppid]: %proc.name -> %evt.type(%evt.args)' syscall.type contains unlink and evt.args contains /tmp`

Comment: Are you sure the file had been created in /tmp/? Add logging to your crontab entry: */4 * * * * echo "hello" > /tmp/test.txt  2>>/home/myuser/test.log